# Powershell - Cannot find virtual/network drives in a remote-session

Tags: powershell-3.0

I think it's a bug, want to make sure.

If I run the "subst" command in powershell on the remote computer, it shows me the mapped virtual drives (as it would on a cmd prompt)

But if I run the same command from remote powershell session from my computer, it won't return anything. Even Get-PsDrive is returning only the fixed drives available. It's excluding both virtual and network mapped drives

This is how I am entering a remote session: `Enter-PsSession -ComputerName <serverName> -Credential <credentials>`

Does anyone know if it's a bug?

Both I and the remote PC are on powershell Ver: 3 0 -1 -1

Many thanks in advance!
Phani

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a "double hop" problem , try to read this [Enabling Multihop Remoting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting.aspx)

from Hey,Scripting Guy Blog .Hope this helps you.

Daniele

Comment: Thank you very much the reply! The issue I am having is in the first hop, i.e I am connected to only one computer. I tried to search online, but can't find anything. Do you know what else I can look for?

Comment: If the share on the remote session is on another computer it might be a second hop

Comment: The share is on the same PC. It's a virtual drive created from another folder on D:\ (fixed drive on the remote PC), just to reduce the file path lengths. I am able to get around using the full physical path, but would like to know a solution for this problem